# Nextcloud with Traefik - Bad Gateway / Connection Refused

Tags: linux, ip, apache2, traefik, nextcloud

I recently installed Nextcloud over a lamp stack and want to run Traefik in front. For that, I tweaked the apache2 ports.conf to:
`Listen: 127.0.0.1:180`
. Now I also configured a .toml for Traefik that points to this address.
When I try to open the website, it gives me "Bad Gateway".

Trying to solve the error I searched the Traefik logs and found this:

`msg="'502 Bad Gateway' caused by: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:180: connect: connection refused"`

Thinking it must be a problem with trusted_proxies I configured Apache to open it's port to the public and also changed the Traefik .toml to see wheter it would work.

It did. That means that Nextcloud definetly accepts my proxy and the proxying works all good.

Problem is, It doesn't work when I configure it on localhost.
The access.log and nextcloud.log show nothing.

Any help?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, but hidden.
Traefik is a Docker container, so normally it can't communicate with services not in the docker network.

The fix is:
`ip addr show docker0`

Bind Apache2 to this IPv4: (my example) `Listen 172.17.0.1:180` and also modify the Traefik Config.
Then Apache2 will listen on the docker0 network which containers have access to.